# How to hook multiple SR04 Ultrasonics without soldering or using resistors / parts

Tags: sensor

What hat would be appropriate for attaching 3-5 Ultrasonic sensors like the SR04? For this question, assume I have to use a prebuilt 4-pin F-F dupont style connector.

Comment: What is the hat for?  I.e. why aren't you just connecting the sensors directly to the Pi?

Comment: probably because I googled and not one hit said that was possible. But even if it was, what 3-5 sets of pins provide gnd, 5V, and 2 digital signals each?

Comment: Ground and 5V may be shared between all the sensors.  That's just a wiring problem.  So you need two gpios per sensor, so 6-10 gpios.  You will need resistors to voltage divide the 5V sensor output to a Pi safe 3.3V.  I suppose you might find such a hat.  It will be expensive as it's likely to be a one-off.

Comment: You are not telling me anything I do not know (www.spiked3.com). I have a specific purpose in mind, and a very specific question.